# Setting a default value if a variable is empty

Tags: php

I have one field Style, in this field I have few options to select, but what I want is when the person doesn't select any style, in the field I want to display the text "N/A"
How I can do that?

Now display nothing if i dont select the style
[image: Style Option]

[image: Style Edit]

```
<dt> Style </dt>
<dd> <?php $styles=styles(); 
if(isset($styles[$user->style]))echo $styles[$user->style];
?> </dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP7, you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to give a default value when a variable isn't set:

```
echo $styles[$user->style] ?? 'N/A'
```

In earlier versions, use the ternary operator:

```
echo isset($styles[$user->style]) ? $styles[$user->style] : 'N/A';
```